# R: How to print variable named "Q" in debug mode?

Tags: r, debugging, rstudio

I am debugging in RStudio, and I have a function with a variable defined in the function's environment called `Q`. I would like to inspect it by printing it on the console by typing `Q`, but that ends the debugging session. How to print the value of `Q` without ending the debugging session in RStudio?

Comment: Well, this question answers itself: `print(Q)`.

Comment: How about `eval(Q)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use the function `print(Q)` or `eval(Q)`